# Border around sticky matColumn in matTable

Tags: css, html-table, css-selectors, sticky, siblings

I have a matTable with the first two or three columns sticky. The problem is, due to the border styling already in place for the table, the area where the non-sticky columns scroll under the sticky columns looks like a glitch instead of sticky behavior:

[image: Sticky column loses 3D effect from matching column border when scrolled under]

I want to add a unique border style (or any type of style, really), but I am running into opposite problems for the headers and the body cells:

1. All the column headers have the exact same list of classes, so I am unable to write a selector that will select only the sticky ones:

[image: mat-table-sticky on both sticky and non-sticky columns]

2. The body cells only have `mat-table-sticky` on the actual sticky columns, so I can select them, but since the sibling selectors only select siblings after a given sibling, I can't select the last sticky column; `last-child` and `last-of-type` also don't appear to care that I'm just looking at the sticky columns.

Any suggestions for how I might put a border (or any styling at all) on only the last sticky column?

Edit: HTML code setting the sticky status:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns">
  <ng-container matColumnDef={{column.displayName}} [sticky]="column.sticky"> <!-- column.sticky determines whether a given column is sticky -->
    <th mat-header-cell>{{column.displayName}}</th>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `nth-child` will solve your problem `th:nth-child(x)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

```css
body{
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
    position: relative;
}

th{
  margin-right:1rem;
}


.first-table th:nth-child(4){
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr class="first-table">
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">4th child</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="second-table">
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
        <th class="mat-sticky">Savings</th>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified that the columns are *marked* as being sticky; they aren't sticky because of their position, but because of their content, so relying on position isn't going to work.

Comment: i added code snippet for you,  can you check it please if you know which child needs to change you can reach it with `nth-child` @Trevortni or if you add a reproducable example we can check it cause i actually don't understand what do you want

Comment: I added the HTML code setting the sticky attribute to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up calling a function from each cell that looks at the next column and returns a `sticky-edge` class if the column is on the edge:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
  <ng-container matColumnDef={{column.displayName}} [sticky]="column.sticky"> <!-- column.sticky determines whether a given column is sticky -->
    <th mat-header-cell [class]="getStickyEdgeClass(i)">{{column.displayName}}</th>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

```
getStickyEdgeClass(index: number){
  if (columns.length > index + 1 && columns[index].sticky && !columns[i + 1].sticky)
    return "sticky-edge";
  else
    return "";
}
```

```
.sticky-edge {
  border-right-color: black;
}
```

It would have been nice to be able to do this with pure css, but I guess if you can't, you can't. Still hoping someone might show me a way that you can.

Comment: maybe you should add angular to tags because i don't understand the pure css translation of your question. Maybe somebody who knows both angular and pure css can answer your question